# Maintaining different repositories under a master project repository

Tags: git, version-control, perforce

We are into a project that involves many opensource libraries and their code.
Our application uses all these libraries code to build an X application.
The problem comes when individual libraries get updated and we have to support these updated 
librayies,which leads to a lot of manual copying of latest code and merging of changes that we made on the previous versions of the updated libraries.

We have our own version control in place (perforce) but its repo is there just to version our changes along with all the code of opensource libraries that we use.

Is there a way in which the individual libraries can be updated through there own version control systems(they might be using there own versioning systems of their choice git,svn,etc..) by perforce .. i mean we give a command to sync on perforce and it does the individual syncing on individual libs using their respective versioning tool?

If perforce cant do this is there another tool than can do this? which one is the preferred tool for such a use case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at how the [chromium project](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code) does this - they have *hundreds* of third-party dependencies, and a home-grown set of scripts to maintain separate checkouts for them (at fixed revisions, from their own mirrors, of course). The master repository isn't perforce, but the scripts work fine on both git and svn, so they should be adaptable to p4 as well.